# Recyclerview with view binding, click listener

Tags: android, kotlin

Iam trying without succes to add detailview (onclick listener) after click on recyclerview item.
Iam using viewbinding and thats new to me.

My code for the adapter:

```
class MyRecyclerAdapter(listitems: MyFragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    var items: ArrayList<ListItems> = ArrayList()

//     class MyViewHolder(val binding: LayoutMyListBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)





    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
                LayoutMyListBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        parent,
                        false
                )
        )
    }
    class MyViewHolder(var LayoutMyListBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(appInfo: ListItem) {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                println("clicked for detail")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.listItem.text = items[position].titel


    }

    fun submitList(ItemsList: ArrayList<ListItem>) {
        items = ListItems as ArrayList<ListItem>

    }

}
```

How can i implement the click listener with viewbinding in the adapter ? i know i can do holder.binding.setonclicklistener. But this is a bad option.

I I solved it so set an click listener on the ViewHolder

Comment: *But this is a bad option.*, no ... it's better option.. there is no need for setting listener multiple times(every time when view is reused)

Answer (score 1):

The `bind()` never get called, so call it in `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.vacatureTitel.text = items[position].titel
    holder.binding.vacatureWerkgever.text = items[position].werkgever.bedrijfsnaam + " gevestigd in " + items[position].werkgever.werkgever_plaatsnaam

   holder.bind(items[position]) // <<< Change here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it to put an clicklistener on the Viewholder.